# Differentiability of value function

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $X$ is a process given by -

$dX_t = db_t$ 
where $b_t$ is a standard Brownian motion with its filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$.

Suppose an agent earns a payoff given by

$V(x) = \mathbb{E} [\int_0^\infty e^{-\int_0^t r(X_s)ds} dt|X_0 =x] $

where $r(x) = \begin{cases} 3 & \text{ if } x \ge 0 \\
7 & \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$

I am interested in computing $V(x)$. In particular, I am interested in knowing if $V(x)$ is differentiable at $0$?

I suspect that the answer is no for differentiability. But I don't have a proof.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's differentiable (everywhere).
Interchanging operations freely, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\newcommand{\D}{\frac{\mathrm d}{{\mathrm d}x}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}
V'(x) &=& \D \E_x \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\left(\int_0^t 3+4[W_s<0]\mathrm ds\right)\right)\mathrm dt
\\
&=&  \int_0^\infty \E_0 \D\exp\left(-\left(\int_0^t 3+4[W_s<-x]\mathrm ds\right)\right)\mathrm dt
\end{eqnarray*}
Then we end up needing
$$
L^x(t) := \D \int_0^t [W_s<x]\,\mathrm ds.
$$
If we try to interchange the $\D$ with the $\int$ here it seems to not exist at $x=W_s$. However, we don't need to as, as far as I can tell, this is just the [local time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) of $W$ at $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can sort of understand your argument. But here's a related question then. Assuming it is differentiable, I can compute the functional form explicitly as, when $x > 0$,

$3 V(x) = 1 + 1/2 V''(x)$ and a similar DE when $x \le 0$. 

Now, I can solve these, kill one constant by conditions at $\infty$ and $-\infty$. For the remaining two constants I use continuity and differentiability at $0$. 

But here's an alternative way of getting $V(0)$. If $r = 3$ throughout then $V(0) = 1/3$. If $r = 7$, then $V(0) = 1/7$. Therefore, in our case, $V(0) = \frac{1/3 + 1/7}{2}$.

Comment: The values computed using the two approaches don't match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure  $V''$ exists

Comment: Yes, $V''$ won't exist at $0$, certainly. But when $x > 0$ and when $x < 0$, it will exist and I can use the DEs I mentioned, I think. And then, I can get the two constants using continuity and differentiability at $0$.

Comment: Also, in going from line 1 to 2, should it not be $W_s < -x$ instead of $x$?

Comment: @Aditya you're right, I fixed the sign now.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Sorry to bother you with one more question then. If you need the derivative of $\int_0^t [W_s < -x] ds$ how does that translate to requiring the derivative of $\int_0^t [ W_s < x ] ds$?

Comment: By substitution and the chain rule from ordinary calculus

Comment: Great. Many thanks for your help. :)